# Test AngularJs view where template is read from a file

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I want to test an AngularJs view with an external template.  Almost all the examples I have found demonstrate code like this:

```
var element = angular.element('<div>something goes here... </div>');
element = $compile(element)(scope)
```

But my HTML is a little more complicated than that so I want the test to read it from a file.  Where can I find an example of that?

Answer (score 0):

I found a great post here: http://www.zealake.com/2014/01/01/unit-test-your-angularjs-views.

Here is a snippet of my own code:

## Initialize the controller and a mock scope

```
beforeEach inject ($controller, $rootScope, $templateCache, $compile) ->
  scope = $rootScope.$new()
  # CaseCtrl = $controller 'CaseCtrl',
  #   $scope: scope
  template = $templateCache.get TEMPLATE_URL
  if !template
    template = $ajax(TEMPLATE_URL, { async: false}).responseText;
    $templateCache.put TEMPLATE_URL, template

  element = angular.element template
  element = $compile(element) scope
  scope.$apply()

it 'should ...', ->
  expect($(element).html()).toBe 'This is the case view.'
```